# How I add div tag with class before every table in the article and add div closeing tag after table closing tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add `<div class="">` before `<table>` and also `</div>` after `</table>` dynamically with javascript. How I can do it.

Answer (score 3):

You have jQuery as a tag so assuming you already have that you can use the [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function.

To wrap all tables you could do

```
$('table').wrap('<div class=""></div>');
```

Comment: but need one ' end of div tag

Comment: @MohammedAbuFaysal ah yes you're right, have fixed my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You are looking for this:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //before added
    console.log($('.main-content').html());
  
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("table").wrap("<div class='AddedTag'></div>");
       //after added
       console.log($('.main-content').html());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="main-content">
  
   <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Test table col</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
   
 </div>
 <button>Click to add</button>
```